# Rounding Issue using Math.Round

Tags: c#, vb.net, math, rounding, bankers-rounding

```
Module Module1
Public Sub Main()
    Dim values() As Double = {43.523, 12.65, 43.565}
    For Each value As Double In values
        Console.WriteLine("{0} --> {1}", value, Math.Round(value, 2))
    Next
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
End Module
```

The above code results as

- 43.523 --> 43.52
- 12.65 --> 12.65
- 43.565 --> 43.56

I need 43.565 --> 43.57 and not 43.565 --> 43.56. 
But i still need the other 43.523 --> 43.52 and 12.65 --> 12.65 rounded as is.

Comment: But note that "Because of the loss of precision that can result from representing decimal values as floating-point numbers or performing arithmetic operations on floating-point values, in some cases the `Round(Double, Int32, MidpointRounding)` method may not appear to round midpoint values as specified by the mode parameter." For `Round(43.565,2,mode)`, it does, since although the `Double` closest to 43.565 is smaller than that, multiplying by 100 yields exactly 4356.5, so the value rounded to an integer _is_ a midpoint. But for 2.135, you get 2.13, since the rounded value isn't a midpoint.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, if exact decimal values are of concern to you, you should consider using `Decimal` instead of `Double`. In particular, 43.565 isn't *exactly* representable as a `Double` to start with.

However, if you want to specify the behaviour for "midpoints" (i.e. where it could reasonably round up or down), use the [overload with a `MidpointRounding` parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5898377.aspx):

```
Console.WriteLine("{0} --> {1}", value, _
                  Math.Round(value, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero))
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use:

```
Math.Round(value, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

For details, see the [overload of Math.Round](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f5898377.aspx) which accepts a `MidpointRounding`.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
Math.Round(value, 2, System.MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [MidpointRounding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.midpointrounding.aspx) parameter:

```
Math.Round(43.565, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Should give you 43.57